# How to include non node module Jquery plugin in an Angular 2 - Webpack App

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular, webpack

I am using [ng2-admin template](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin) and trying to include [Sly](http://darsa.in/sly/#!documentation) in it, but I am struggling to add it.

I simply added jquery and Sly links inside my Index.html, but I am not sure how to Import Sly inside my Component.

**webpack.common.js:**

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery",
    ...
  }),
```

**analysis.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
var Sly = require('../../../assets/plugins/sly/sly')
import 'style-loader!./analysis.scss';

@Component({
    selector: 'analysis',
    templateUrl: './analysis.html'
})
export class AnalysisComponent implements OnInit {
    public acreage: any = {
        condition: { good: 46, ok: 27, bad: 27 }
    }
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Sly', Sly)
        var sly = new Sly('#frame', { horizontal: true }, {
            load: function () {
                console.log('load')
            },
            move: [
                function () {
                    console.log('move 1')
                },
                function () {
                    console.log('move 2')
                }
            ]
        });
        sly.init();
    }
}
```

I am getting following error in browser's console:

> Sly is not a constructor

An error simply means that the Sly plugin is not imported. 
How to import and use non node module Jquery plugin inside Angular 2 Webpack app. The complete code of the template I am using can be found [here](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin).

Comment: found a solution?